# Timestamp Precision Cut-off

Tags: pg-promise

This plpgsql function expects many parameters and returns a table-like recordset. This is how it looks like executing inside of pgAdmin Query Tool

[image]

As we can see the highlighted column is a `timestamp` consists of **6-digits** after decimal for `PST`. Calling it this way:

```
var sql = 'select * from myschema.myfunc($1, $2, ...);';
var datavalue = ['a549daa0-66b5-4122-936f-8f5c65055d29', '2021-03-17', '2021-04-16', -1];
db.task(async t =>
  { return t.any(sql, datavalue);}
  ).then(gooddata =>...).catch(...)
```

Value for `timestamp` column is **3 digits short**, below is the `UTC` value corresponding to row 1 above, missing the last 3 digits **385**

[image]

How do I get 6-digits back or that's the way pg-promise works?

Comment: A side question - why are you using a task to execute a single query? :) Also, `pg-promise` does not do anything with the returned data, it is the [underlying driver](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) function. First check to make what you're getting within pgAdmin when running that query.

Comment: @vitaly-t Thanks for the comment. I was also wondering if I'm using the right call. `.task` was used to `await t.none('DISCARD $1:value', ['TEMP']); return t.any(sql, datavalue);` as the function used to generate a `temp table`. Temp table is no longer the concern now. For a pg function returning a table of data, what's the appropriate method to call it?

Comment: Method `any` just returns you everything, so it is the right one. But as far as the timestamp goes, that's beside the point. It is either your function implementation that cuts the result or a conversion filter. Anyway, it is not the `pg-promise` doing.

Comment: @vitaly-t It's because javascript supports down to milliseconds (**3-digits**) while PostgreSQL timestamp is down to microseconds (**6-digits**), NOT `pg-promise`. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key is **JavaScript and its variants support only 3-digits, it cut off the last 3 digits rather than rounding**.

Solution is to round to 2-digits then compare

`if (select tableTimestamp::timestamp(2) = parameter::timestamp(2) from mytable where ...) then  Update mytable ...; else raise exception ...; end if;`

P.S., `with` and `without time zone` is confusing.